# How to use a function converted from string after new Date()?

Tags: javascript

I want to output new Date().getDate()

But getDate() is inside a string

```
fn = "getDate()"
d = new Date();


// How do I make it work?
console.log(d.fn);
```

The problem is that I can't use it as it is now.

You can test it on:
http://jsfiddle.net/99tayr5b/

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the method name `getDate` without `()` into a string and use bracket notation:

```
fn = "getDate"
d = new Date();

console.log(d[fn]());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/99tayr5b/1/

Comment: Thanks @tymeJV. This one I like it. I will aprove your answer, but I will not be able to upvote your answer, as I don't have reputation yet. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how do we call this brackets [] _technique_?

Comment: @Tudor -- It's simply called bracket notation

Comment: @Tudor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Thanks again. I found the detailed explantation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Comment: @tymeJV why do I need to get rid of **()** from **getDate**?

Comment: @Tudor -- Because you can't use that within the string to trigger the function call.

Comment: @Tudor: Simply because the property is called `getDate`, not `getDate()`.

Answer (score 1):

[`console.log(new Function('obj', 'return obj.' + fn)(d));`](http://jsfiddle.net/99tayr5b/3/) works.
But it's dirty solution and I can't recommend it.